# Use TradingView to display the Golden Cross for a stock

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

How can I use TradingView to display a chart for 1) a symbol and 2) for a specified date range showing:

1. Daily OHLC
2. 50 day EMA
3. 200 day EMA
4. SPY open (or close) price as a line (not OHLC) - as a benchmark

I want this to get a visual about how the Golden Cross works.

Comment: Where exactly do you need help? Are you able to plot some of those points?

Comment: @vitruvius I have just started on TradingView and I have no idea how to do anything. So I am hoping someone can point me to a pine script that does most or all of what I am looking to do. And if most, then I can start with that.